# Rich Text Area is hidden and not displaying anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrapping, bootstrapper

I have implemented action-text in my rails project, I am creating a blog website where user can post their articles. I want a rich text area so that user can add multiple action texts e.g., Bold, Italic, Code, Quotes, etc.

I have done `rails action_text:install` and also `rails active_storage:install`. Then, done the `rails db:migrate`, and eventually added `has_rich_text :body2` in my file *app/model/article.rb*.
And added this  line `<%= form.rich_text_area %>` in my *app/views/articles/_form.html.erb* partial. I have already added bootstrap v5 in my views (for front-end). But when I am trying to run the server and go to the *localhost:3000/articles/new*
my rich text area is not visible.

*app/views/articles/_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_with model: article do |form| %>
  <div>

    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title, placeholder: "Enter the title..." %>
    <% article.errors.full_messages_for(:title).each do |msg| %>
      <div><%= msg %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :body2 %><br>
    <%= form.rich_text_area :body2, placeholder:"Enter the content..." %>
    <%  article.errors.full_messages_for(:body).each do |msg| %>
      <div><%= msg %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= form.number_field :user_id, id: :article_user_id, value: current_user.id, type: :hidden %>
    <%  article.errors.full_messages_for(:body).each do |msg| %>
      <div><%= msg %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :status %><br>
    <%= form.select :status, Article::VALID_STATUSES, selected: article.status %>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div >
    <%= form.submit class: "btn btn-outline-dark" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

*app/models/article.rb*

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  include Visible
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_rich_text :body2
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body2, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }

end
```

*Gemfile*

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.0.4"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.3"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"
gem 'devise', '~> 4.8', '>= 4.8.1'
gem 'rdoc', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
  gem "sqlite3", "1.4.2"

end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
group :production do
  gem "pg", "1.3.5"
end
```

Following is the output:-

[Hidden RICH TEXT AREA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsIHr.png)

Although if I put text_area and try to add HTML it works, (this is proof that rich_text_area is working but not able to work maybe because of bootstrap? )

[Text Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWP9a.png)

[Output with Text Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs1JX.png)

Comment: Please check developer tool -> console and check js error

Comment: Are you importing `trix` and `@rails/actiontext` in your Javascript entry point (i.e., `application.js`)?

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing the same error running `rails assets:precompile` and restarting the rails server resolved the error.